# elliptic curves on general 3-folds of degree 7

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, hypersurfaces

Do there exist elliptic curves on a general 3-fold hypersurface $X_7 \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ of degree $7$?

Clemens proved that for $d \ge 8$ there are no elliptic curves on the general hypersurface $X_d \subset \mathbb{P}^4$. Likewise, Ran [proved](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911161) the case $d = 6$.

[This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1385725888800052) paper of Ferrarese and Romagnoli proves that all such $C$ must have degree a multiple of 7 and for each degree, there can only be finitely many such curves.

However, it is not clear to me if any such curves exist. I do not believe that degree $7$ elliptic curves can appear since Gruson-Lazarsfeld-Peskine shows that any such curve must be $8$-regular and then a dimension count shows that there is no such curve on a general $X_7$.

Comment: The very general hypersurface of large enough degree is “hyperbolic” (so no elliptic curves can map nontrivially to it in particular). I will look later what the precise known degree constraints are.